# Make assigning object properties less redundant when there's structural similarities in ES6

Tags: javascript, oop, object, ecmascript-6

Let's say I'm assigning object properties as follows:

```
d.x += d3.event.dx || 0;
d.y += d3.event.dy || 0;
```

In other words, there's consistency in how the properties are assigned values.

Is there a sugared way to simplify this key value assignment? Es2015 syntax is fine.

Comment: I don't think you can get more simplified than it already is

Comment: @incodeveritas Does requirement include incrementing existing value of `d.x`, `d.y`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys()`, `.forEach()`

```js
var d = { x: 3, y: 4 }, d3 = { event: { dx: 1, dy: 2 } };

Object.keys(d3.event).forEach(prop => d[prop[1]] += d3.event[prop] || 0);

console.log(d);
```

Comment: That is ugly! But, it's a win. I didn't downvote fwiw.

Answer (score 1):

You could use destructuring to eliminate the repetitive dot notation.

```
const { dx, dy } = d3.event;
```

Comment: Would `const { dx, dy } = d3.event` create two additional variables `dx`, `dy`?

Comment: Not additional variables, but it would create variables that would allow the code above to be written as so. `d.x += dx`

Comment: _"Not additional variables, but it would create variables"_? `dx` is not an additional variable?

Comment: Haha ya, I suppose you're right. That statement didn't make sense.